# How can i track changes in job subid

Tags: oracle

[image]I have a table that has emp number, job name, jobid and jobsubid.  i am want be able to identify cases where a jobsubid and job name changes but jobid remains the same and the job name changes to a different name that the previous  case where in both jobid and jobsubid are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function for it. But there must be some column to identify the order of records so i have assume that there must be some `jobstartdate` column

```
Select t.*,
Case when prev_jobname <> jobname and prev_jobsubid <> jobsubid
Then 'Changed'
Else 'Not changed' 
end as result
(Select t.*
Lag(t.jobname) 
 over (partition by t.empno, t.jobid
    Order by t.jobstartdate) as prev_jobname
Lag(t.jobsubid) 
 over (partition by t.empno, t.jobid
    Order by t.jobstartdate) as prev_jobsubid
From your_table t) t
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks , this definitely gives me an idea but suppose the job name was from a  different table how can i write this query  to look into data from two tables or more?

Comment: You can do join with proper condition and use that column data

Comment: I am doing a join as shown on this code but it says there is a problem starting at the second select statement: Select t.*,e.*,
Case when prev_jobname <> jobname and prev_jobsubid <> jobsubid
Then 'Changed'
Else 'Not changed' 
end as result
(Select t.*,e.*,
Lag(t.jobname) 
 over (partition by e.empno, e.jobid
    Order by e.jobstartdate) as prev_jobname
Lag(e.jobsubid) 
 over (partition by e.empno, e.jobid
    Order by t.jobstartdate) as prev_jobsubid
From your_table t, second_table e
where 
your_table.empno=second_table.empno);